# TinyMCE menu bar icons are garbage / mojibake

Tags: character-encoding, tinymce, tinymce-4, mojibake

I just downloaded a fresh copy of tinymce, uploaded it and tried to use it on my UTF-8 encoded website.

The menu bar icons are either garbage because it can't find it's presentation file (font?) or the encoding of one of the 10000 files is wrong.

Anyone knowing this bug? I didn't change anything, just uploaded..

[image]

TinyMCE doesn't use my german lang file either, obviously. I placed the js file into the "langs" folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.baseURL = '//example.com/de/assets/scripts/tinymce';
tinyMCE.suffix = '.min';
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
 });
</script>
```

Do I have to set any configuration for path, basepath, ... ??

My actual path to tinymce is `scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js`. The origin path provided by the shipped package was `tinymce/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js` but honestly this kind of nesting folders without any reason..

**update:** The paths are working, it does read files not directly linked.. (like theme.min.js) successfully.